# Redirect URL with Query code

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect this url: http://www.arenborghoeve.nl/Basis.aspx?Tid=23&Lid=17&Lit=VIEW&Hmi=76&Smi=0&QUERY=ARENU_FAQ_site.Id=2

to a new smart url http://www.arenborghoeve.nl/faq/

Can anyone send me the code ?

I know how to use easy redirects.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: why you've used wordpress tag?

Comment: The new site is a wordpress site

Comment: but you need a solution for the other one, and as I can guess from url it's .NET active server page.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} QUERY=ARENU_FAQ_site
RewriteRule .* http://www.arenborghoeve.nl/faq/? [R=301]
```

Comment: As in it's not redirecting or...?

Comment: With the above, if `QUERY=ARENU_FAQ_site` is in the url, then it should redirect. Can you try it in a different browser?

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not working in my .httaccess file